# Importing variables from a function inside another file

Tags: python, function, import

I'm trying to use a function from another file to generates random values for some variables but it doesn't seem to work

*Function*

```
def common_monsterstat():
  mattack = random.randint(1, 5)
  mdefense = random.randint(0, 1)
  mhealth = random.randint(5, 10)
  mmaxhealth = mhealth
```

*Code that uses function (file name that function is in is named monsterstats.py)*

```
from monsterstats import *

common_monsterstat()

def battlesys():
  print("You challenged Monster!")
  print("Monster's health: " + mhealth)
```

Comment: at the end of function use `return mhealth` and later `mhealth = common_monsterstat()`

Comment: @furas Should mhealth = common_monsterstat() also be inside the function?

Comment: not inside function but instead of `common_monsterstat()` . You have to learn more about functions and `return`

Comment: Please note this is not related to the function location.  All variables within a function are local to that function and cannot be access from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem with scope. When you create a function, every variable you assign a value to is a local variable (unless you use the `global` keyword). You could use the global keyword like this :

```
mhealth=0
def common_monsterstat():
   global mhealth
   mattack = random.randint(1, 5)
   mdefense = random.randint(0, 1)
   mhealth = random.randint(5, 10)
   mmaxhealth = health
def battlesys():
   print("You challenged Monster!")
   print("Monster's health: " + mhealth)
common_monsterstat()
```

This will make your code change the global health instead of creating a copy of it...

But the better way to do this is to simply return the health variable, because global keywords can become confusing after a while in my experience. However, if you need your game to be really efficient, which you probably don't, using global would save you from creating too many variables ( although not sure if it would be more efficient I just think so :)) So, you could do it like this:

```
def common_monsterstat():
      mattack = random.randint(1, 5)
      mdefense = random.randint(0, 1)
      mhealth = random.randint(5, 10)
      mmaxhealth = mhealth
      return mhealth
def battlesys():
  mhealth=common_monsterstat()
  print("You challenged Monster!")
  print("Monster's health: " + mhealth)
common_monsterstat()
battlesys()
```

This will create a `local`variable, assign it a value, return it into another variable, and then print it... Seems more complex but is actually easier...

Tell me if you need any clarifications!
PS: You might wanna have a random name for your monster and use an f-string to name in a cooler way:

```
monsters=['centaurus','dwarf','spider']
def battlesys():
   print(f"You challenged {r.choice(monsters)}!")
   print("Monster's health: " + health)
```

PPS: you didn't import random in your code...

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `def common_monsterstat()` function add a return statement for mmaxhealth. Then at the second code assign mhealth to `common_monsterstat()` function. I recommend u to learn about function, global and local variable at python :)

Here is the fix code:

```py
def common_monsterstat():
  mattack = random.randint(1, 5)
  mdefense = random.randint(0, 1)
  mhealth = random.randint(5, 10)
  mmaxhealth = mhealth

  return mmaxhealth
```

```py
from monsterstats import *

mhealth= common_monsterstat()

def battlesys():
  global mhealth

  print("You challenged Monster!")
  print("Monster's health: " + mhealth)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having all free floating variables, it might be easier to group them in a class. For example you can have a class for generic stats, and create a factory function that creates instances of that class.

```
class Stats:
    def __init__(self, attack, defense, health, maxhealth):
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.health = health
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth


def common_monsterstat():
    mattack = random.randint(1, 5)
    mdefense = random.randint(0, 1)
    mhealth = random.randint(5, 10)
    mmaxhealth = mhealth
    
    return Stats(
        attack=mattack,
        defense=mdefense,
        health=mhealth,
        maxhealth=mmaxhealth,
    )
```

In the main method you can then use the factory method to retrieve the stats:

```
from monsterstats import *

stats = common_monsterstat()

def battlesys():
  print("You challenged Monster!")
  print("Monster's health: " + stats.health)
```

To make writing this class even easier, you could take advantage of a dataclass, which is perfect for pure data objects.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Stats:
    attack: int
    defense: int
    health: int
    maxhealth: int

...
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's just setting up data, don't use a function.  Yu can define constants that get imported by name.  In "monsterstatps.py":

```
import random
mattack = random.randint(1, 5)
mdefense = random.randint(0, 1)
mhealth = random.randint(5, 10)
```

Then in your "main.py":

```
from monsterstats import *

def battlesys():
  print("You challenged Monster!")
  print("Monster's health: " + mhealth)
```

In the long term, you might define a `class Stats` that contains these values, and import an instance of that class.